# Is there a way to get the last USED/READ document in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to find a way to get the last USED/READ element (not created).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this, but you can't do this!
But you can activate log for query and check running queries.

Step 1. `Configures the profiler level.`
select database and run this command `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`

Step 2. `Get query list`
run db.system.profile.find()

In result you can find query->filter | depend on this you can guess last USED/READ.

Comment: I need this because I want to find a way firstly: to get Timestamp of last created document. I am using: db.collection('xxx).find().sort( { _id : -1 } ).limit(1); so I get the last document but cant return  ObjectId and timestamp of it.
later on I will work on last used docs..

Comment: last inserted document time you can get from mongo documentId.
Please check `https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/`